# Look and Feel - Java

Tags: java, java-swing, look-and-feel

Tengo mi JFrame (llamado frmMenuPrincipal que contiene un JMenuBar con opciones) que le he puesto en el main el siguiente codigo para que tenga un buen diseño:

```
try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Este es el diseño que se muestra cuando lo ejecuto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego he creado una ventana JInternalFrame que en el main le coloque el siguiente codigo:

```
try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsClassicLookAndFeel");
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Este es el diseño cuando lo visualizo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cuando visualizo el JInternalFrame me aprece con el diseño de WindowsClassic pero cuando ejecuto el JFrame osea el Menu Principal me aparece con el diseño de windows (eso esta bien) pero cuando hago click en las opciones del JMenuBar me abre el JInternalFrame con el diseño de windows y no el diseño de windowsclassic. 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Como haria para que cada ventana cuando se habra aparezca con su propio diseño que se coloco.

Comment: ¿puedes postear las imágenes de el resultado actual y el esperado?

Comment: ya ahorita lo edito

Comment: ya lo edite @x4mp73r

Comment: puedes intercalar look and feels para simular que tienes dos... usa los mismos codigos que utilizas (los `UIManager.setLookAndFeel(...)`), pero tienes que agregar esto SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(referenciaATuFrame); para que se aplique el look and feel en tiempo de ejecucion al frame que necesitas (evidentemente, tienes que correr el `setLookAndFeel` cada que cambies de ventana). Referente a esto, cómo puedes hacerlo, o en donde debes poner ese código?

Answer (score 1):

Una mala noticia y una buena...

La mala: el UIManager coloca el look and feel en un singleton y solo tiene espacio para un look and feel (lo que quiere decir que no puedes tener dos look and feels al mismo tiempo).

La buena noticia: puedes intercalar look and feels para simular que tienes dos... usa los mismos codigos que utilizas (los UIManager.setLookAndFeel(...)), pero tienes que agregar esto `SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(referenciaATuFrame);` para que se aplique el look and feel en tiempo de ejecucion al frame que necesitas (evidentemente, tienes que correr el setLookAndFeel cada que cambies de ventana).

Que bueno que no necesitas tener dos look and feels en el mismo frame (por ejemplo, para dos paneles diferentes) por que alli tendrias que meterte a sobreescribir (override) por componente individual `JComponent.setUI();` y eso es mas complejo para los resultados que necesitas.